# Java/Kotlin: When trying to read from copied Excel file that contains data and has not yet been opened/saved - the data is not readable - no output

Tags: java, excel, kotlin, apache-poi

I am having an issue figuring this one out.
As the title says, when I am trying to read from an Excel file that is a copy of another Excel that has not yet been opened and saved —  my function will not read data as I try to put them in a `.txt` file

```
while (Excel().excelReader(filePath, rowExcel.toString(), "A", 4) != null)
{
     data.appendText(Excel().excelReader(filePath, rowExcel.toString(), "A", 4)+"\r\n")
     rowExcel++
}
```

This code works perfectly fine whenever I open and save the file FIRST. But of course, I don't want to do that.
Is there a way to get around this?

The function that reads the data:

```java
fun excelReader(filePath: String, row: String, col: String, sheet: Int): String {
    var fis = FileInputStream(filePath)
    var wb = XSSWorkbook(fis)
    var sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheet)
    var evaluator: FormulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator()
    wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll()
    
    var cellReference = CellReference(col+row)
    var row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow())
    var cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol().toInt())
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
    
    var cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell)
    var result = cellValue.getStringValue()
    return result    
}
```

I tried writing data to Excel first which works but still didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be looking for answer this is what I did to resolve it.
Now the file will work with my function from OP even without opening/saving the file first.

```
try
{
     var wb = XSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream(File(filePath)))
     XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb)
     var out = FileOutputStream(filePath)
     wb.write(out)
     out.close()
     wb = XSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream(File(filePath)))
}
catch(ex: IOException)
{
     ex.printStackTrace()
}
```